# Codeigniter - Ajax not working no return value

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
echo '<script>$( "#start").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "'. base_url() .'StartTest/session",
      data: "id=' .$row->id .'",
      success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
        if(result == "' .$row->id .'"){
          window.location.replace("'. base_url() .'StartTest/index/0");
        }
      }
    });  
  });
</script> ';
```

In my view page, when user select a test, I want to store the testid in session and redirect to TestView page.

I used the ajax above to but nothing happen after I click start link.
Below are my controller class:

```
public function session(){
    if($this->input->post('id')){
        $s_v = array(
            'testid' => $this->input->post('id')
            );
       $this->session->set_userdata($s_v);
       echo $this->session->userdata('testid');
    }else{
        echo "asd";
    }
}
public function index(){
    // Get Test ID
    $id = $this->session->userdata('testid');
    ...
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;
    $data['question'] = $this->TestModel->getAllQuestion($id, $page);
    $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $this->load->view('TestView',$data);
}
```

Comment: Where are you returning data to client side??

Comment: Actually I no need return my flow is when start button clicked, ajax -> StartTest/session store test id then  window.location.replace("'. base_url() .'StartTest/index/0"); go to the TestView, sorry I am beginner of codeigniter so not sure the concept are correct or not

Comment: Please advice if the concept are wrong or is there a better way to do.

Answer (score 0):

In ajax post you have to follow a valid format.

here, instead of

`data: "id=' .$row->id .'",`

try

`data : { id : "<?php echo $row->id ?>" },`

Hope it will halp you.
Thank You

Comment: Still the same, I try ajaxerror, it got print out so I suspect my ajax didnt work.

Comment: yahh, i know. Can you tell me what is the error show in your browser.

Comment: try this `data: { id :"' .$row->id .'"},`

Comment: error: function(request,error) 
{
 console.log(arguments);
 alert ( " Can't do because: " + error );
} Then it print Can't do because error. So not exact msg show what it caused.

Comment: did you try my last comment ?Actually your jquery ajax format is wrong.

Comment: Ya tried too, same. No alert, unless adding in the error function, alert the error.

Comment: add 'echo' before every php element in jquery.

Comment: Ya I even empty the session method and echo "something", inside the sussess: function (result) { alert("ssssss"); }.

Comment: use <script type="text/javascript"> instead of <script>

Comment: `echo '<script type="text/javascript">$( "#start").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "'.echo base_url();.'StartTest/session",
      data: { id : "'.echo $row->id; .'" },
      success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
        if(result == "'.echo $row->id;.'"){
          window.location.replace("'.echo base_url();.'StartTest/index/0");
        }
      }
    });  
  });
</script> ';`